# POSIX ways for generation of a temporary file with a nice file name

Tags: c, file, posix, rename, temporary-files

I want to generate a temporary file with a "nice" name like

`my-app-Mar27-120357-Qf3K0a.html`

while following the best practices for [security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).

POSIX offers me `mkstemp(3)` which takes a filename template (typically something like `/tmp/my-app-XXXXXX`) but it has two problems:

1. I need to choose the output directory myself. [When I see glibc `tempnam(3)` (which is deprecated for a security reason) considers many factors](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Temporary-Files.html#index-tempnam), I wish to let the library function choose it.
2. There's no extension in the file name

The second item can be addressed by `mkstemps(3)` which takes a number of characters to keep as a user-defined extension.  In my case, I can pass `my-app-Mar27-120357-XXXXXX.html` and `5`
but it has its own problems:

1. I still need to choose the output directory
2. It isn't perfectly portable. NetBSD seems to lack it.

So I'm considering to use the deprecated `tempnam(3)` to generate a filename with the output directory path, overwrite the filename part with `X` and feed it to `mkstemp(3)`, and then rename the file to my preferred format. So the problem lies in the last step, renaming without overwrite; is it possible in POSIX?

Or could there be any better alternatives?

Comment: The answer from Alex is what I would recommend too, but there is a standard C function [`tmpnam`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/tmpnam) you could use if you really want a name.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `tmpnam(3)` is less flexible than `tempnam(3)` which I've already mentioned in my post.

Comment: [NetBSD 7.0](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?mkstemps++NetBSD-7.0) and newer have `mkstemps`.  However it is not currently present in Minix3 libc.

Comment: @kdhp I apparently checking with "DEFAULT (NetBSD-6.1.5)". Perhaps it defaulted to a conservative choice.

Answer (score 1):

Let `mkstemp` make the file it wants to make, in the POSIX-compliant way that it wants to. Use `symlink` to make a symbolic link from a source file and path of your choice to a destination that matches whatever comes from using `mkstemp`. Remove the symbolic link when you're done.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot say I love this solution... "Remove the symbolic link when you're done." Imagine I'm working on a crash dump which my program prompts the user to send to our server by email or web upload. But yeah, this might be the closest thing to my intention.

Comment: If you are throwing an exception that causes a fatal error, you could (should) deal with clean-up in that exception's handler.

Comment: I mean temp files can legitimately outlive their producer program in some of quite common use cases.

Comment: @nodakai if you are worried about stray symlinks or tempfiles remaining following a crash, that's generally what `trap` will take care of for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to simply munge the template and add your path. We describe such a function in the BEDOPS toolkit here, used by the `sort-bed` application to allow the end user to specify where temporary intermediate files are stored: https://github.com/bedops/bedops/blob/6da835468565dfc30a3fcb65807e91fcf133ea2b/applications/bed/sort-bed/src/SortDetails.cpp#L115

```
FILE *
createTmpFile(char const* path, char** fileName)
{
    FILE* fp;
    int fd;
    char* tmpl;

    if (path == NULL)
        {
            fileName = NULL;
            return tmpfile();
        }

    tmpl = static_cast<char*>( malloc(1 + strlen(path) + L_tmpnam) );
    strcpy(tmpl, path);
    strcpy(tmpl+strlen(path), "/sb.XXXXXX");
    fd = mkstemp(tmpl);
    if(fd == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "unable to create temp file!\n");
            return NULL;
        }
    fp = fdopen(fd, "wb+");
    *fileName = static_cast<char*>( malloc(strlen(tmpl) + 1) );
    strcpy(*fileName, tmpl);
    free(tmpl);
    return fp;
}
```

This uses the `L_tmpnam` macro, part of the `stdio` library, to set the number of characters that the variable `tmpl` (the filename, ultimately) can store.

This compiles and works under Linux and OS X (BSD) hosts and also uses POSIX routines.

It is more complex than my other solution but it might work better for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for sharing an actual example. You're working on an interesting project, btw